# Nextjs13 client side data fetching

Tags: node.js, token, next.js13

I am a learning Nextjs and for my app I am using nodejs for backend and nextjs for frontend. After the user log in to the account I need to store the token. The protected routes needs token to fetch data from backend but fetching the token and making the request to backend making every page client component because of use of UseEffect. Because of that I can't use async/await for data fetching, is there any solution to this. Please understand that I am new learner

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please tell me how to store token in cookies and how to make request to protected routes in frontend

Comment: please show your code, and read how to ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use async/await in client components. Something else is wrong, probably what the error message suggests, but it's hard to tell without the code

Comment: Could you please explain how to use async/await in client components

Comment: @learner you cannot use async/await in a client component because it is reserved for server components if it is already a client component then you can use useEffect hook.

Comment: Thank you @alpha_N1618. Could you please tell me how do we store token in cookie and send the token withrequest. I am using Nextjs for frontend and Nodejs for backend